# how to get parquet file name based on data in table

Tags: hadoop, hive, parquet

I'm trying to figure out in which of the many parquet files is the data stored in table for a particular set of date condition.

For example:

```
select filenames from table where dateCol = '1-1-2010';
```

I remember this reading somewhere that it's possible but couldn't recollect anything as such; neither could I find it elsewhere. Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

```
select distinct(INPUT__FILE__NAME) from table where conditions;
```